# In "simple-arbitrage" code, where does the abi.ts come from? Is this hand written or this is from uniswap provided info?

Tags: uniswap, flashbots, arbitrage

Where does this [abi.ts](https://github.com/flashbots/simple-arbitrage/blob/master/src/abi.ts) come from?
I was comparing it with Uniswap code [here](https://unpkg.com/@uniswap/v2-periphery@1.1.0-beta.0/build/IUniswapV2Router02.json):

but they don't look the same. Thanks